# Postgresql FATAL: could not create lock file "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock": Permission denied

Tags: postgresql

I try to start postgresql : `/usr/pgsql-11/bin/pg_ctl -D appli/postgres/data/ -l logfile start`
but I don't understand why I have always this error in my logfile :

```
FATAL:  could not create lock file "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock": Permission denied
```

I tried to change permission but I get always Permission denied :

```
chown -R postgres:postgres /var/run/postgresql
chmod 755 /var/run/postgresql
```

Comment: Try running from postgres user.

Comment: @SaurabhNigam when I try to run : `sudo -u postgres postges` I have this error: `sorry, user XXX is not allowed to execute '/bin/psql' as postgres`

Comment: I guess it requires `775`

Comment: @Thirumal I have same error when I try chmod 775

Comment: This `chmod 755 /var/run/postgresql` doesn't change sub directories permission, requires `-R`

Answer (score 4):

Edit `postgresql.conf` and change `unix_socket_directories` back to the factory default value `/tmp`.

Alternatively, start PostgreSQL as operating system user `postgres`.

Comment: I'm actually keep getting the same error

Answer (score 4):

I ran into it with an `alpine` `docker` image. As it turned out they [changed](https://git.alpinelinux.org/aports/tree/main/postgresql14/unix_socket_directories.patch?h=3.15-stable) the default:

> Using /tmp for sockets allows everyone to spoof a PostgreSQL server.

There are 2 options:

1. Create the `/run/postgresql` dir:

   ```
   mkdir /run/postgresql && chown postgres: /run/postgresql
   ```
2. Change `unix_socket_directories` in `postgresql.conf` (`unix_socket_directories = '/tmp'`).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and what did it for me was creating the directory "postgresql" which didn't exist previously for some bizarre reason and running

`sudo chown postgres /var/run/postgresql`

after that pg_ctl was able to create the lock file without problems.

Answer (score 1):

Actually in the directory `/var/run/postgresql` only root user has the privilege of write and the command you are trying to start the server with `(pg_ctl)` tries to generate lock file that prevents multiple instances of server on the same port at the same time. The user that you are trying the command with has not the `write` permission therefore you get the `permission denied` error.

You can not run this command as root either as it will refuse to do so therefore the only possible solution is that you make changes in the `postgres.conf` file.

In `postgres.conf` file Assign `unix_socket_directories` to `/tmp`. On `/tmp` directory other users have also write privilege other than root.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed from source, the directory should probably be '/tmp'.  If you installed from a repository, the shipped start-up script should handle the permissions for you. Why not use that rather than running pg_ctl yourself?

Answer (score 0):

For citus postresql extension installed on wsl2 I created .sh file to start  postgres manually:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sudo mkdir -p /var/run/postgresql
sudo chown postgres:postgres /var/run/postgresql
sudo chmod 744 /var/run/postgresql

sudo -u nobody bash -c : && RUNAS="sudo -u postgres"

#Runs bash with commands between '_' as nobody if possible
$RUNAS bash<<_
cd ~/
source ~/.bashrc
pg_ctl -D citus -l citus_logfile start
_
```